# Trying to get users in Active Directory using LDAP showing only distinguishedName and Path

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, adsi

I am trying to retrieve a set of users available in Active Directory using LDAP with PowerShell, but I am only getting the response shown below:

```
[adsi]'LDAP://DomainController.com/DC=DomainName,DC=com'
```

And it successfully executes with just the two statements below:

```
distinguishedName : {DC=DomainName,DC=com} 
Path              : LDAP://DomainController.com/DC=DomainName,DC=com?
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Take a look at the [Get-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617241.aspx) command, it's built specifically to get user details from AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally I got the answer using Get-AdUser

The statement is

```
Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=yourdomain,dc=com" -server "yourDomainControllerName" | select SamAccountName
```

Comment: `SearchBase` is only needed if you want to query a specific OU, it will search domain root by default. `Server` is only needed if you want to query a _specific_ domain controller, if you don't include this parameter the command will pick a DC automatically. So you can query every user in every OU just by using: `Get-AdUser -Filter *  | select SamAccountName`

Comment: yes, and exactly I wanted to search a specific server only..Thank you @JamesC.